# Some Error Happening when Simulating Attack against libssh

Tags: networking, libssh

when I was simulating ssh attack for the bug CVE-2018-10933. I met the following error:
[the output I encountered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtfxP.png)
It seemed that there is some error in the exce_command function. Any help would be appreciated.

My paramiko version is 2.0.8; I have tried libssh-0.7.4 and libssh-0.7.5, all with the same problem.

The code I have used is this link:
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/46307

Comment: Please paste the error message here

Comment: THank you so much for your comment, actually, the error message is in the link of the picture "the output I encountered"

Comment: Yes, but please paste it as text here. Images are very uncomfortable to read and may be removed one day. Also, the error will not be caught by the search engine

Comment: ERROR:root:Channel closed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "libssh.py", line 28, in execute
    client.exec_command("id")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 62, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 240, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1143, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
None

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!